# Disable stderr from external library

Tags: python, subprocess, stderr

I need to disable sys.stderr messages, which produced by some *.jar file.

This *.jar file is calling by `subprocess.check_call(cmd)` from `sklear2pmml`  method `__init__.py` of external library (**sklear2pmml** library).

I know, that I can disable stderr by changing library code to something like this:

```
fnull = open(os.devnull,'w')
subprocess.check_call(cmd,stderr=fnull)
```

But this treak leads to changing python library, that I don't want. How can I fix stderr output without this side effect?

Answer (score 3):

One option could be to temporarily redirect `sys.stderr` like this:

```
old_stderr = sys.stderr
sys.stderr = open(os.devnull, "w")
# put your library call here
sys.stderr = old_stderr
```

That's assuming you don't call the library too many times -- I think this could be quite an expensive thing to do.

**EDIT (the original answer is wrong):**

This is actually a bit deeper -- Python's redirection doesn't affect the STDERR file descriptor of the process. You need to close and reopen the file descriptor of your process. This is described in the following blog post, which also provides an implementation (for STDOUT):

http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2015/redirecting-all-kinds-of-stdout-in-python/

I had to change the code from the blog slightly to make it work with my version of Python, I'm adding the affected lines:

```
# Create a new sys.stdout that points to the redirected fd
import codecs
sys.stdout = codecs.getreader("utf-8")(os.fdopen(original_stdout_fd, 'wb'))
```

Comment: I've already tried this trick - unfortunately, I still can see in console output error messages from those *.jar..

Comment: If I understand correctly, the reason why this trick does't helped described [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html):
"Changing these objects doesn’t affect the standard I/O streams of processes executed by os.popen(), os.system() or the exec*() family of functions in the os module."