# Can I suppress protobuf deserialization error messages in Python

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

I am trying multiple message formats to decode a persisted binary protobuf message (I don't think protobuf binary gives you a way to find out the message type).

```
for message_type in message_types:
    try:
        with open(bin_file, 'rb') as stream:
            message_type.FromString(stream.read())
    except google.protobuf.message.DecodeError:
        pass
```

This works, but all `message_type`s that fail parsing the binary stream print errors to stderr, such as

```
[libprotobuf ERROR T:\src\github\protobuf\protobuf\src\google\protobuf\wire_format_lite.cc:577] String field 'MyMessage.WarningMessages' contains invalid UTF-8 data when parsing a protocol buffer. Use the 'bytes' type if you intend to send raw bytes.
```

Since they do not print to the python object `sys.stderr`, changing that one doesn't help.

Can I prevent protobuf from printing errors?

I am using a fresh protobuf==3.13.0 installation.

Answer (score 0):

What protobuf version are you on? I'm using `3.12.4` and I don't see any chatter on stderr. Do you have any environment variables set or logging level flags which might be causing the underlying library to emit messages?

Try in a more bare environment with more isolated code.

Edit: I see now what is happening. Not sure how to reproduce it (tried feeding b'\xff' which should be invalid unicode but still don't see the library error), but in general you want to look for answers on how to suppress stderr from external libraries:
[Disable stderr from external library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45283185/disable-stderr-from-external-library)

Comment: Using `3.13.0` myself. Maybe it's because the messages I'm using are similar enough to trip protobuf over? (Updated the question with the kind of stderr noise I am getting)